# What is the [conflicts] tag meant for?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [conflicts](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conflicts) tag seems to be getting used for a number of different questions. It primarily seems to be used to refer to situations in Fate/Fate Core, but is also tagged on a few questions about Polaris, Mouse Guard, Dogs in the Vineyard, and some other systems.

However, the tag also seems to be getting used on some questions to refer to conflicts outside of a game.

If it's meant to refer to a specific in-game mechanic in certain RPGs, it's possible it fills a niche that isn't already covered by [party](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/party), [player-vs-player](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/player-vs-player), [betrayal](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/betrayal), and similar tags. That said, it seems like it might refer to either different mechanics in the various systems (which might warrant separate tags), or more generally to all sorts of in-character conflict (...which seems quite broad).

The use of the tag for out-of-game conflict seems more questionable, as there seems to be much more potential overlap with tags like [group-dynamics](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group-dynamics), [social-contract](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-contract), [social](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social), [problem-players](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/problem-players)/[problem-gm](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/problem-gm), etc. (Of course, none of these is totally identical to the scope of "any out-of-game conflict", which also seems quite broad.)

The usage guidance for [conflicts](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conflicts) suggests that it's the former:

> In-game conflicts can be social, physical, or any other realm of conflict. In some game systems, conflicts are the smallest unit of mechanical resolution.

It doesn't clearly state that the tag is *only* to be used for in-game conflict, though perhaps that's meant to be assumed by its failure to mention out-of-game conflict. If it is meant to refer to only in-game conflict, perhaps the usage guidance should be made more explicit so the tag isn't added to irrelevant questions.

**When should the [conflicts](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conflicts) tag be used? Does it have a clear scope distinct from that of other tags?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Conflicts are a scene mechanic. The tag was created for use in Fate questions, and has also been adopted for a couple of other games are which have a Conflict mechanic.

I can't speak to Mouse Guard, but in DitV and Fate the Conflict system is about resolving people coming to blows over something. Distinctly, in Fate, the mechanic is abstract: this isn't about physical combat. It can also be a verbal spat, a court case, or other scene types. This makes [combat](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combat) not appropriate.

We should clarify the tag wiki and prune where it's being used incorrectly.

Answer (score -6):

I can think of no valid reason, save for a game mechanic that has this name, to use this tag on its own. Since that is our stance on "is that a valid tag", I think the mechanics should be separated out and put into a safe harbor (or 3), the rest goes to be burninated. Or to quote the Spaß Marines:

**Burn, Purge, Kill**

Comment: The “tag can’t be used on its own” test for meta tags has to be modified at RPG.se. For example, [combat] can’t be used on its own, but it’s not a meta tag. And yet, [combat] needs at least one tag describing a relevant system. So instead, we have to use a test that doesn’t count system tags. Since [conflicts] *can* stand on its own beside a system tag, it’s not a meta tag.